# How to generate infinite sequence with itertools

Tags: python, sequence, python-itertools

I would like to generate two infinitive series of 0 and 1 and specifically in the following order:

0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, ...

I have created the following code which does not return what except:

```
# for in loop
for i in itertools.cycle(range(0,2)):
    if i == 0:
        i += 1
        if i == 1:
            i -= 1
            if i == 0:
                i -= 1
                print(i, end = " ")
```

It just returns a series of -1. Cannot figure out where the error is. Can anyone give any suggestions

Comment: The reason you only see -1 is because your print statement is inside that nested `if` statement and only runs when that condition is satisfied.

Comment: All your `if` statements are ***nested*** and you print only after `i` becomes `-1`.

Comment: There really isn't a way to implement your logic without littering your loop with print statements. You also have no way of exiting this infinite loop -- which is fundamentally different behavior from an infinite *sequence* from which you can yield values at any time. With a `for` loop used like this, your program won't be able to do anything else other than print these values. With a generator and `next()`, you can have your program perform other tasks whenever you want, and when you want the next value in the sequence, at any time, you just need to call `next()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're insisting on using `itertools.cycle` in a `for` loop like this, but here's one way you could make this work:

```py
for i in itertools.cycle(range(0, 2)):
    if i == 0:
        print(i, end=" ")
        i += 1
        print(i, end=" ")
        i -= 1
        print(i, end=" ")
        i -= 1
        print(i, end=" ")
```

Note that there's really no point in using your nested `if` statements, since each nested predicate will always be true: if `i` is zero, and then you add one to it, then *of course* your nested predicate `if i == 1` will be true...

In addition, your use of `itertools.cycle` in a `for` loop is an anti-pattern. As shown in BrokenBenchmark's answer, you can simply cycle over the elements of the sequence itself, forever. If you *insist* on using the `for` loop:

```py
for i in itertools.cycle([0, 1, 0, -1]):
    print(i, end=" ")
```

There are so many things wrong with this approach though. Namely, as I discussed in the comments, this is an infinite ***loop*** which is a fundamentally different behavior than an infinite ***sequence***. With an infinite loop, nothing else can ever happen -- your program will be stuck cycling over your four elements forever with no way to do anything else.

If you use `itertools.cycle` as it's meant to be used -- as a generator -- you can pick up where you left off in the sequence at any time, allowing you to perform other tasks for as long as you want before continuing your sequence:

```py
c = itertools.cycle((0, 1, 0, -1))
next(c) # 0
next(c) # 1
next(c) # 0
next(c) # -1

# do something else for a while
next(c) # 0

# yield the next 10 items from the sequence
for _ in range(10):
    print(next(c), end=" ")

# do something else again
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks that was such educational. Anyway, since I should create an infinite generator, maybe I thought - mistakenly - that the easiest and most common way was looped. Mine was a pretty naive attempt (that's why I found a trivial solution with an if statement). If you would like to add some further suggestions to try out a better solution in the future that would be appreciated. Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) in a way that explicitly states the elements you want to generate:

```py
from itertools import cycle
cycle([0, 1, 0, -1])
```

Comment: Thanks. Would that be possible to implement the intertool function within a loop?

Comment: @mały_statystyczny that kind of defeats the purpose of using `itertools.cycle`

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can implement your own generator with some simple modular arithmetic:

```py
def seq():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield (-1)**(i // 2) * (i % 2)
        i = (i + 1) % 4  # keeps i small, so as not to take up too much memory
```

Demo:

```py
>>> s = seq()
>>> [next(s) for _ in range(10)]
[0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1]
```

I know OP states that they specifically want to use itertools, but this may still be helpful to others.

As pointed out in a comment, you can also simply emulate `itertools.cycle` by passing arbitrary args and using `yield from` (note that `itertools.cycle` actually works differently under the hood):

```py
def seq(*args):
    while True:
        yield from args


s = seq(0, 1, 0, -1)
```

But that's not as fun as figuring out the actual arithmetic sequence in my opinion :D

Comment: How about `while True: yield from (0, 1, 0, -1)` :)?

Comment: Yep, but that's not as fun :D

Comment: Thanks this answer was pretty exhaustive. But I was wondering how to use both code together. I mean the itertools module at the head of a loop as follows

Comment: As I stated in another comment, that kind of defeats the purpose. You'll also get an infinite loop `for i in itertools.cycle(range(0, 2))` will loop forever if you don't add a break statement, which is not the same behavior as an infinite sequence.